# NodeJS infinite running terminal app with read from terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a terminal app that will run indefinitely and will have the ability to read from the terminal.

I tried to user the "readline" api but the app terminates without waiting for any input.

I added a "while(true)" loop but it seems that the thread gets stacked in the loop and does not respond to my input.

I need a series of random numbers.
To accomplice it I added an interval of 1000ms and the result was the same with while loop.

To summary I need to create an app that reads from the terminal and create random numbers on a given interval.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

**Edit 1**
Additional information I just thought to give you.

I tried to put either the readline call or the interval in a separate forked process but nothing changed.

Also I tried to use recursion for the readline.

**Edit 2**
Although I accepted @amangpt777`s answer I would like to give another problem that you might encounter.

I was calling my script like this 'clear | node ./script.js' on windows` powershell.

I believe that it was the pipe that was blocking my input.

I don't know if this can happen on linux, I haven't tested it.

I just add it here so you keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. But following code will take input from user using readline and will keep on storing the input in an array. Note that I have some commented code in this which can be uncommented if you want a publish subscriber model. Also that you will need to add more code to sanitize and validate your input. I hope you will get some pointers to achieve what you want with this:

```
var readline = require('readline');
//var redis = require('redis');
//let subscriber = redis.createClient();
//let publisher = redis.createClient();
let numEntered = [];

var r1 = readline.createInterface(
   {
      "input": process.stdin,
      "output": process.stdout
   }
);

// subscriber.subscribe('myFunc');
// subscriber.on('message', (channel, msg) => {
//    //Your logic
// });

function printMyArr(){
   console.log("Numbers entered till now: ", numEntered);
}

function askNumber(){
   askQuestion('Next Number?\n')
   .then(ans => {
      handleAnswer(ans);
   })
   .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
   })
}

function handleAnswer(inputNumber) {
   if(inputNumber === 'e') {
      console.log('Exiting!');
      r1.close();
      process.exit();
   }
   else {
      numEntered.push(parseInt(inputNumber));
      //publisher.publish('myFunc', parseInt(inputNumber));
      //   OR
      printMyArr();
      askNumber();
   }
}

function askQuestion(q) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      r1.question(q, (ans) => {
         return resolve(ans);
      });
   });
}

function init() {
   askQuestion('Enter Stream. Press e and enter to end input stream!\n')
   .then(ans => {
      handleAnswer(ans);
   })
   .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
   })
}

init();
```

Comment: Also note that you can remove askNumber function and instead of calling `askNumber();` in `handleAnswer` you can directly call `askQuestion().then().catch()`. But I find former approach cleaner.

Comment: I can modify your example and add the interval and do my tests. I thank you very match I will accept and study your answer.